# Accessing files and storage data on Android 13

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I was able to access the storage files on android version 12, yet once I upgraded to version 13, I always get the following error:

> I/flutter (16455): [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception:
> PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allowed
> reading external storage, null, null) I/flutter (16455): Unsupported
> operation PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not
> allowed reading external storage, null, null)

I will provide my code:

```
static Future<List<PlatformFile>> pickFiles(
    BuildContext context,
          List<PlatformFile> alreadySelected, {
            int maxFiles = AppConfig.maxAllowedFiles,
          }) async {
        final androidInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
        print("Andorid ingo $androidInfo") ;
        Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statusess = {};
    if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt <= 32) {
      print("IAm here") ;
      statusess = await [Permission.storage].request();
    } else {
      statusess = await [Permission.photos].request();
      print("IAm her2e") ;

    }

    print("statusess $statusess") ;
    var allAccepted = true;

    statusess.forEach((permission, status) {
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        allAccepted = false;
      }
    });

    if (allAccepted) {
      if (maxFiles > 1 && alreadySelected.length >= maxFiles) {
        _showSnackBar(
          context,
          "You can't select more than $maxFiles file${maxFiles > 1 ? 's' : ''}",
        );
        return null;
      }

      final fromCamera = await showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        useRootNavigator: true,
        builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
          title: const Text('Source'),
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              title: const Text('Camera'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.folder_open_outlined),
              title: const Text('Files'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

      if (fromCamera == null) return null;

      if (fromCamera) {
        final picker = ImagePicker();
        final uncompressedPickedFile = await picker.getImage(
          source: ImageSource.camera,
          imageQuality: 60,
        );
        final pickedFile = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
            uncompressedPickedFile.path, "${uncompressedPickedFile.path}_compress.jpg");

        if (pickedFile != null) {
          final pickedFileAsFile = File(pickedFile.path);
          final platformFile = PlatformFile(
            path: pickedFile.path,
            name: pickedFileAsFile.path
                .substring(pickedFileAsFile.path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
            bytes: await pickedFileAsFile.readAsBytes(),
            size: (await pickedFileAsFile.stat()).size,
          );
          return [
            if (maxFiles > 1) ...alreadySelected,
            platformFile,
          ];
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }

      FilePickerResult result;
      try {
        result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          type: FileType.custom,
          allowedExtensions: AppConfig.allowedFileExtensions,
          withData: true,
          allowMultiple: maxFiles > 1,
        );
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Unsupported operation $e');
      }
      if (result != null) {
        final filteredExtensions = result.files.where(
              (file) => AppConfig.allowedFileExtensions.contains(
            file.extension.toLowerCase(),
          ),
        );
        if (filteredExtensions.length < result.files.length) {
          _showSnackBar(
            context,
            'Unsupported file extensions were not added',
          );
        }

        final allowedFiles = filteredExtensions.where(
              (file) => (file.size / 1024 / 1024) < AppConfig.maxAllowedFileSize,
        );
        if (allowedFiles.length < filteredExtensions.length) {
          _showSnackBar(
            context,
            'Files larger than ${AppConfig.maxAllowedFileSize} MB were not added',
          );
        }
        if (maxFiles == 1) {
          if (allowedFiles.isEmpty) return null;
          return [allowedFiles.first];
        }
        final filesToReturn = [...alreadySelected];
        for (final file in allowedFiles) {
          if (alreadySelected.any((f) => f.path == file.path)) {
            continue;
          } else {
            filesToReturn.add(file);
            if (filesToReturn.length >= AppConfig.maxAllowedFiles) {
              _showSnackBar(
                context,
                'Only the first ${AppConfig.maxAllowedFiles} files were added',
              );
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return filesToReturn;
      }
    }
  return null;
}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

reading storage in android 13 is bit different here how you can do it:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

and for storage permision:

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> requestPermissionAndroid13() async {
    final permission2 = Permission.photos;
    final permission3 = Permission.camera;
    if (await permission2.isDenied) {
      print("---photos permission---");
      await permission2.request();
    }
    if (await permission3.isDenied) {
      await permission3.request();
    }
}
```

i hope it will be helpful :]